# facebook reset cache on "Share on Facebook" links

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I just updated our site's `<meta>`'s open graph protocol. I just noticed that whenever I share some links, the old `<meta>` is the one being parsed by Facebook. However, to those links I run on [debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) tool they show the updated `<meta>`. Is there a way to have Facebook recognized updated `<meta>` on all links aside from pasting it on debugger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When You update your `<meta>` (`Open graph`) tags and run it through the [debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) You are **updating and clearing Facebook servers cache**, Not Yours!

**Clear Your  browser cache** and you should see the updated `<meta>` tags