# Wrong image in thumbnail when a url is shared

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

When i share this link es.fubles.com/matches/2465171
the thumbnail image is not the same specified in meta tag og:image

[image: Problem Description]

If you debug this link there is no errors and the image is correctly loaded
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fes.fubles.com%2Fmatches%2F2465171

What I'm wrong?

-- Update --

To reproduce you can use this link
http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fes.fubles.com%2Fmatches%2F2464510
and you have to increment the number at the end of the url until you will see the wrong blue image  (2464511 .. 2464512..).

Now if you'll refresh the page, you will see the right image! (soccer ball)

Comment: You can follow this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19899697/facebook-reset-cache-on-share-on-facebook-links/19912265#19912265

Comment: I cleared my browser cache and the result is the same :(

Comment: Well, It works fine with me :/

Comment: Now the link used as sample (2465171) works fine me too, it is very strange issue, I add to my post the info to reproduce the issue.
I think it happen only when you share for the first time an url.