# Facebook og:image Showing in Debugger but not on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

When checking in the debugger, my image shows up fine and I even get the preview of 'When shared, this is what will be included'... but when I try to share the link on Facebook, the bit where the image should go is blank.

I see no kind of errors or warnings in the debugger though so I have no idea what could be wrong?

I've done this countless times in the past without issues, I don't recall this happening before. Could it be due to how this server / hosting is set up perhaps?

Comment: Are you trying the same link over and over? Facebook caches link and related images, so if you tried a link that failed once it can take days before the Facebook cache expires.

Comment: Try **"fetch new scrape information"** button here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/. This button forces fetching new data from desired URL and, I believe, also invalidates old cached data.

Comment: @AndersBornholm Facebook clears its current cache once you fetch new scrape data/debug the url, but you're also required to clear your browser's cache as well http://stackoverflow.com/a/19912265/2151050

Comment: What was the solution? I am seeing the same issue. The open graph debugger looks fine, but my share post is empty. I have refetched the data on Facebook and cleared my browser cache.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?  I'm having this issue as well.

Comment: Having the same issue. And I have been for days. You can see it here. The image shows up fine in the debugger (and even when I pasted the link to create the post), but not on the facebook page after the post is published. https://www.facebook.com/ccupboard/

Comment: UPDATE: Of course, when I post about it, it goes away inexplicably.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, maybe has something to do with the app id?